# pandas: slice Multindex with many indices

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I have a dataframe `d` with about `100,000,000` rows and `3` columns. It looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd 

In [17]: d = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'n': [34, 22, 95, 86, 44]}) 

In [18]: d.set_index(['id', 'val'], inplace = True)
```

I have another dataframe with values of `id` and `val` that I want to keep in `d`. There are around 600,000 combinations of `id` and `val` that I want to keep:

```
In [20]: keep = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a', 'b'], 'val' : [1, 2]})
```

I have tried this in the following way:

```
In [21]: keep.set_index(['id', 'val'], inplace = True)

In [22]: d.loc[d.index.isin(keep.index), :] 
Out [22]:         
                   n
         id val    
          a  1    34
          b  2    22
```

This works but seems clunky and is very slow. Is there a better approach here? What is the fastest way to slice on Multindex in pandas?

Comment: OP!  Please accept [WeNYoBen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56583154/2336654)'s answer as I believe you'll get a 2x speed up.

Comment: Thanks! Just noting here that `MultiIndex.from_frame` is new in .24. Annoyingly, I have to run this on a server with pandas .23.

Comment: Then a combination should work `d.reindex(list(zip(*map(keep.get, keep)))])`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This seems way faster than .loc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `reindex`

```
d.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(keep))
Out[151]: 
         n
id val    
a  1    34
b  2    22
```

Comment: TIL `pd.MultiIndex.from_frame`

Comment: This answer has two advantages over mine: **1.** `reindex` is faster and I should've used it over `loc` but I wanted less characters.  **2.** `pd.MultiIndex.from_frame` is fast as well.

Comment: Yup, I did brainfart this question and also TIL from_frame. Nice touch!

Comment: @WeNYoBen this works in the toy example from my question, when I have a unique MultiIndex on `d` . In my real data set, I get the following: `Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!` Any suggestions?

Comment: @svenkatesh then you may need using isin method , also for code safety , it is better do not keep duplicate index .

Answer (score 5):

`loc` takes a list of tuples for referencing a `MultiIndex`

```
d.loc[[*keep.itertuples(index=False)]]

         n
id val    
a  1    34
b  2    22
```

---

A more obnoxious way to do the same thing. (Not actually a recommendation)

```
d.loc[[*zip(*map(keep.get, keep))]]

         n
id val    
a  1    34
b  2    22
```

The advantage is 3 less characters.  You only have to sacrifice understanding what is going on.

Comment: I like the succinctness of this but I doubt `itertuples` will address the "What is the fastest way to slice on Multindex in pandas?". Second one should.

Comment: Thanks -- `d.loc[[*keep.itertuples(index=False)]]` gives me a syntax error but `d.loc[keep.itertuples(index=False)]` works.

Comment: @svenkatesh that is a python version issue.  Use what works for you

Comment: @cs95 `keep.itertuples(index=False, name=False)` is just as fast.  It's the creating of the namedtuples that slows it down.

Answer (score 3):

Use `loc` to index `d` using `keep`:

```
# d.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([keep['id'], keep['val']]))]
d.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([keep['id'], keep['val']])))

         n
id val    
a  1    34
b  2    22
```

Where,

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([keep['id'], keep['val']])

MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b'], [1, 2]],
           codes=[[0, 1], [0, 1]],
           names=['id', 'val'])
```

Generates a MultiIndex from `keep` that is used to filter.

---

Another option is to try merging with `df.merge`:

```
d.merge(keep, left_index=True, right_on=['id', 'val'])

    n id  val
0  34  a    1
1  22  b    2
```

```
d.merge(keep, left_index=True, right_on=['id', 'val']).set_index(['n', 'id'])

       val
n  id     
34 a     1
22 b     2
```

Or even,

```
d.join(keep.set_index(['id', 'val']), how='inner')

         n
id val    
a  1    34
b  2    22
```

Comment: This is cute `d.merge(keep, on=[*keep]).set_index([*keep])`

Comment: @piRSquared Nice, works for this example with these column names :)